# How to tell to Selenium Manager to use the same version of CfT as locally installed version of Chrome is?

Tags: seleniummanager, cft

Unfortunately the [offical documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#automated-browser-management) didn't answer the question.

> Let's consider again the typical example of driving Chrome with
> Selenium. And this time, suppose Chrome is not installed on the local
> machine when starting a new session). In that case, the current stable
> CfT release will be discovered, downloaded, and cached (in
> ~/.cache/selenium/chrome) by Selenium Manager.
>
> But there is more. In addition to the stable browser version, Selenium
> Manager also allows downloading older browser versions (in the case of
> CfT, starting in version 113, the first version published as CfT). To
> set a browser version with Selenium, we use a browser option called
> browserVersion.

And by default the locally installed version of Chrome (not Chrome for Testing) is used. So all I need is to force Selenium Manager to use Chrome for Testing instead of locally installed Chrome, but version of Chrome for Testing should be the same as locally installed Chrome.

Tried to use `browserVersion = stable` but it didn't help.
Code samples on any language are accepted as answer.

Also please anyone with reputation > 1500 create tag selenium-manager, so I will be able to update the tag. (Done)